# Avoid Using _this inside of nested function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to improve my code overall, although the following code does work, I want to avoid using _this (to me a hacky way of doing it ), and start using either .call/.apply or .bind to set the context of this on the following example.

Here is the code and the link to jsfiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/W9m3e/4/).

```
(function (window, $) {
'use strict';

var ButtonEffect, button;


Function Constructor
ButtonEffect = function (elem) {
    this.button = $( elem );
};

//Prototype Chain
ButtonEffect.prototype = {
    addEffect : function (ref) {
        return $(this.button, ref).addClass('custom-effect-1');  
    },
    btnObserver : function () {
        //Don't want to use this approach 
        var _this = this;
        this.button.on({
            click : function () {
                //Want to call addEffect without using _this/that #hack             
                _this.addEffect($(this));

            }
        });
    }

};

button = new ButtonEffect('.my-button');
button.btnObserver();


(window, window.jQuery));
```

Here is another Solution i came up with [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xyqML/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems more appropriate to use the built in jQuery methods for passing data to the event handler, that way `this` still references the element inside the handler

```
(function (window, $) {
    'use strict';

    var ButtonEffect, button;

    ButtonEffect = function (elem) {
        this.button = $( elem );
    };

    ButtonEffect.prototype = {
        addEffect : function (ref) {
            return $(this.button, ref).addClass('custom-effect-1');  
        },
        btnObserver : function () {
            this.button.on( {
                click : function (e) {
                    e.data.scope.addEffect($(this));
                }
            }, {scope: this});
        }

    };

    button = new ButtonEffect('.my-button');
    button.btnObserver();


}(window, window.jQuery));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/W9m3e/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, didn't know that you can pass, the scope to on method.
What are your thoughts on this solution http://jsfiddle.net/xyqML/1/

Comment: @DavidStrada - That works fine, but now you've lost the reference to the element the event handler is acting upon, which is usually not a good thing, but if you'll never need to know what element was bound, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this:

```
    btnObserver : function () {
        this.button.on({
            click : function (ev) {
                this.addEffect($(ev.currentTarget));

            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

`ev.currentTarget` is usually the same as what `this` would be if `bind` is not used. And `bind` makes it so that the value of `this` inside your event handler is the same as the scope in which `bind` executes. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzCz4/2).

Comment: Thanks, but there is no need to wrap $(ev.currentTarget) inside of $(), it already does that for you, see http://jsfiddle.net/xyqML/1/

Comment: `$(ev.currentTarget)` is equivalent to `$(this)` in your code.

Comment: mmm... why does ev.currentTarget works then ? see here jsfiddle.net/xyqML/1

Comment: @DavidStrada - because you wrap it again in the addEffect method

Comment: I'll be more verbose: `$()` is needed in `$(ev.currentTarget)` in what I proposed to the *exact same extent* that `$()` is needed in `$(this)` in your code (i.e. not at all). I did not go into `addEffect` to notice that you could have used `this` instead of `$(this)`. My code reflects this.

Comment: @adeneo I'm using `currentTarget` not `target`.

Comment: @Louis - didn't notice, then it would in most cases be the same as `this`

Comment: @DavidStrada One source of confusion is that I did not notice the link you've added at the very end of your question until just now. So I based my answer on your *initial* code, not the one you've added afterwards. (I was probably checking out your first fiddle and writing my answer while you were adding it.)